# How to implement slick-carousel autoplay

Tags: javascript, slick.js, autoplay

I'm pretty new to web dev and sorry if my English is broken.
I'm trying to implement Slick autoplay on this section where the tooltips should appear automatically. I have implemented the arrows which work perfectly, but beside this I also need the autoplay. Can someone give me any ideas how to slick-carousel autoplay?

[HTML]

```html
<section class="section showcase" id="section2">
  <div class="second-background"></div>
  <div class="map" id="pin-container">
     <div class="slider">
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-left slide-left"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-right slide-right"></i>
     </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

[JS]

```js
function initServicesSlider() {
   var width = $(window).width();

   if (width <= 992) {
      $('.service-slider').slick({
         mobileFirst: true,
         touchThreshold: 10,
      });
      $('.services div .slide-right').click(function () {
         $('.service-slider').slick('slickNext');
      });
      $('.services div .slide-left').click(function () {
         $('.service-slider').slick('slickPrev');
      });
}
```

It has to be something with:

```
$(.'service-slider').slick({
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
})
```

but I don't know how to implement it.

PS: I did import slick-carousel

Thanks for the help !:)

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Wfjp3.png

Comment: ```$(.'service-slider')``` is that a typing error?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few things here:

1. You need to close the `if` statement

```
 if (width <= 992) {
      $('.service-slider').slick({
         mobileFirst: true,
         touchThreshold: 10,
      });
      $('.services div .slide-right').click(function () {
         $('.service-slider').slick('slickNext');
      });
      $('.services div .slide-left').click(function () {
         $('.service-slider').slick('slickPrev');
      });
  }
```

2. `$(.'service-slider')` should be `$('.service-slider').slick...` (moving the period into the string).
3. You are calling a class that, in your HTML above, does not exist. You just need to call `$('.slider').slick...`.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the markup fixes #1 and #2 recommended by @nihiser, you should combine all of your Slick initialization code in one call:

```js
$('.service-slider').slick({
  mobileFirst: true,
  touchThreshold: 10,
  autoplay: true,
  autoplaySpeed: 3000,
});
```

This is assuming that you are including your slides with markup that looks like this:

```html
    <div class="slider">
       <div class="service-slider">
           <div>Slide 1 Contents</div>
           <div>Slide 2 Contents</div>
           <div>Slide 3 Contents</div>
           ...
       </div>
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-left slide-left"></i>
       <i class="fas fa-chevron-right slide-right"></i>
   </div>
```

You don't want to include your arrows in the `<div>` that contains your slides or Slick will treat them as additional slides.